# is this a fiber internet outlet or do I need a fiber ethernet converter?

Tags: ethernet

Was wondering if this was a fiber internet port or do I need to buy a converter so I can use fiber internet ?[image]

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ul2p.jpg[image][image]

Comment: Uh... that looks like a phone jack.

Comment: And the wire coming down off it is *almost certainly* phone cable.

Comment: Perhaps you should move the bed so you can get a proper close up shot...

Comment: After you move the bed, crop your pictures, pretty pretty please

Comment: At this point I think everyone said it's a phone back or Ethernet port so no fiber

Answer (score 2):

As far as the image quality allows to guess, this looks like some [registered jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack). It seems smaller than `RJ45` (Ethernet), so it's probably some telephone outlet. Since all `RJxx` are for copper wires, this isn't a fiber internet outlet, most certainly.

Here's a telephone wall jack:

[image]

---

Fiber optic cable wall jacks / outlets (wall "plates" as [these guys call them](http://www.fiber-optic-cable-sale.com/category/cable-management/fiber-optic-wall-plate)?) 
could look something like this:

[image]

but also could just come as a cable with a plug at its end:

[image: like this]

**Edit:** As @Xen2050 kindly pointed out, there are fiber wall outlets. (Thanks!)

Comment: This one is even worse, sorry. Make sure to hold your camera calm when pressing the shutter button, or use the flash light / set up better lighting conditions.

Comment: +1. FYI they do make [fiber wall jacks](http://www.fiber-optic-cable-sale.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/wall-plate-pic-3.jpg) ("plates" as [these guys call them](http://www.fiber-optic-cable-sale.com/category/cable-management/fiber-optic-wall-plate)?). I'm just guessing but being glass, fiber seems like it would be even less flexible than copper, so dangling a wire out of the wall doesn't seem very reliable

Comment: @Xen2050 Thanks for the information! Didn't know that they make fiber wall jacks / plates.

Comment: I wasn't sure either, but thought they must, so searched. I might as well edit the link & image into your answer instead of leaving in  comments (and I can copy & paste the formatting slightly easier & delete these comments later too), but edit/delete if you prefer

Comment: Was mostly interested if it was fiber outlet because I heard they have lasers in them that can be harmful and this is my son's room don't want him to be hurt or anything .

Comment: @Johndoe No need to worry. Even if it was a fiber outlet, it would probably be dead unless you ordered fiber to your home. And even if it wasn't dead, the laser would probably not cause any harm.

Comment: Yeah after everyone answers here I could see it's definitely not a fiber outlet since it's like one hole and the fiber seems to have 2 cables and it def doesnt look the same in terms of outlet look. I assume fiber outlets aren't built into houses only ethernet

Comment: @Johndoe You're right. If your house had a fiber connection, then it would be probably somewhere in the basement, and not in some room somewhere in the house.

Comment: Yeah we don't have a basement I'm currently In a one floor apartment so I don't really know how it would work lol but this has been very Insightful I really do enjoy this website alot of good people here

Answer (score 1):

Based on your picture that looks like a standard [registered jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack).  As for which one, its hard to say from the picture.  Regardless, it is *not* a fiber connection.

Households do not have fiber connections wired throughout the house.  Internet service providers that provide fiber to your home, like Verizon FiOS, bring the fiber connection to a junction box on, or in, your house.  Similar to the following image:

[image]

The fiber connection stops there and then goes to your modem/router, typically via your home's cable TV wiring, called [coaxial wiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_cable).  Your PC, laptops, etc, connect to this device by ethernet or WiFi.

That jack is most likely just a simple RJ-11 phone jack for a telephone.